# Is there a way to add a constant button at the bottom of md-autocomplete items?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to use md-autocomplete directive of angular-material to search users. Users can filter and display list but I couldn't find a way to add a custom button at the bottom of the list. This ("Show all results") button will be shown once on each search which will redirect to another page.

```
<md-autocomplete ng-disabled="vm.search.isDisabled" md-no-cache="vm.search.noCache" md-selected-item="vm.search.selectedItem"
       md-search-text-change="vm.searchTextChange(searchText)" md-search-text="searchText" md-selected-item-change="vm.selectedItemChange(item)"
       md-items="item in vm.userSearch(searchText)" md-item-text="item.displayName" md-min-length="1" md-clear-button="true" placeholder="Search"
       md-menu-class="search-autocomplete-template">

   <md-item-template>
       <span md-highlight-text="searchText">{{item.displayName}}</span>
   </md-item-template>

   <md-not-found>
       No matches found.
   </md-not-found>

   <md-button class="show-more-button" ng-click="vm.showMore()" >
       <span>Show all results</span>
   </md-button>

</md-autocomplete>
```